# Flask HTML Module access Views.py function's attribute

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm creating a dashboard at the moment where I am creating a navigation bar based on table names in a database (this part is all okay).

In views.py I have (**Edit:** Have added the rest of the views.py):

```
    from flask import render_template
from app import app

import sqlite3, json

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',title='Homepage',)
def nav_bar():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\\SQLite\\Databases\\testPython.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE TYPE = \'table\';')
        #ORDER BY NAME ASC
        #tableNames = cursor.fetchall()

    connection.close()

    tableNames = json.dumps(cursor.fetchall()).replace("\"], [\"", " ").replace("[[\"","").replace("\"]]","").replace("access_","").split()

    return tableNames
```

I've created the navigation in navigation.html where the code is -

```
{% for names in navBar.tableNames %}
    <h1>Test</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** here's the base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div style="height:7%; background-color: #171819;"><a href="/" style="color: white; vertical-align: middle; text-decoration: none; font-family: Sans-serif; font-size: 20px; position: relative; transform: translateY(-50%); top: 35%; padding-left: 5%">Access Log Dashboard >>></a></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="column-left" style="float: left; width: 15%; background-color: #3c3f42; height: 93%">
            {% include 'navigation.html' %}
          </div>
          <div class="column-centre" style="display: inline-block; width: 80%; color: #3c3f42;">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I access the attributes in views.py from navigation.html? Sorry if this is a newby question, I assume it is!

Comment: Can you send you please add your views.py questions ??

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi have added the additional bits of views.py, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to pass the tables names return from nav_bar function to your render template   like this :

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

import sqlite3, json

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    table_names = nav_bar()
    return render_template('base.html',title='Homepage',table_names = table_name)
def nav_bar():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('C:\\SQLite\\Databases\\testPython.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE TYPE = \'table\';')
        #ORDER BY NAME ASC
        #tableNames = cursor.fetchall()

    connection.close()

    table_names = json.dumps(cursor.fetchall()).replace("\"], [\"", " ").replace("[[\"","").replace("\"]]","").replace("access_","").split()

    return table_names
```

and then call it to your template like this :

```
{% for names in table_names %}
    <h1>names</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can I do it as a module rather than a template? As I want to basically hook navigation.html to base.html, rather to index, I know I could have this on each page but I'd rather just have it on the base.html. Sorry for being a pain!

Comment: please be specific and tell me what you want? upvote if the answer helps you, i will going to edit it

Comment: Will edit my question to add the base.hml. But I have base.html to include the navigation.html and want to basically have that as a module and not a template. 

From the module it will be able to access the nav_bar() function to pick up the table_names variable. In the module it will then create a list of <a hrefs> (I've not added this yet but its what I do in the future) and then that will be found in each of pages from the base.html.

Comment: Ok!! Do it I will help you

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it a lot :)